# node.js get client IP from http request object

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get the clients IP address from the http req object?

**IE:**

```
   var util = require('util'),
    colors = require('colors'),
    http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('../../lib/node-http-proxy');

//
// Http Server with proxyRequest Handler and Latency
//
var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  // GET IP address here
  // var ip = ??
  var buffer = httpProxy.buffer(req);
  setTimeout(function () {
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
      port: 9000,
      host: 'localhost',
      buffer: buffer
    });
  }, 200);
}).listen(8004);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should just be `req.connection.remoteAddress`

Answer (score 5):

That is usually the correct location to get the client's IP address, but not always. If you are using Nginx, Apache, or another reverse proxy in front of node.js you may have to get the IP address from req.headers. Common names for the header with the remote IP address include "X-Remote-IP" or "X-Originating-IP" but different servers use different header names.

Comment: The defacto standard for proxy servers is `X-Forwarded-For`. It is supported out of the box for most caching proxies, and can be configured in nginx with:  `proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`

Answer (score 0):

It should just be req.connection.remoteAddress or req.ip

Answer (score 0):

Since 16.0.0 it is:

```js
req.socket.remoteAddress
```

which returns a string; `connection` was just an alias for `socket` and is now deprecated.